# Opening a rails.vim related file in a new window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I like rails.vim support for going to the corresponding file.  For example, if I'm in the Product model, I can type `:Econtroller` to open the ProductsController *in the same window.*

I want to open the controller in either a newly created window or else in a different, but existing window.

How would I do that?

For example, to open a file, you can type `:e filename` to open in the same window and `:sp filename` to open in a new window.  I want the `:sp` version of `:Econtroller`, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `:Econtroller` type `:EScontroller` to open in a new split.  There are several more commands in the docs.

After checking the third time, I found the answer in plain sight in [the docs](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/7ea50ede5420058d3d5142d1a5d635ce876486cf/doc/rails.txt#L214). see `:help rails-type-navigation`

Comment: You may also type `:RVcontroller` to open in a new vertical split.

Comment: Also, you can do `:AS` and `:AV` to get alternate files (usually tests or specs) in split and vertical split windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapping defined by the plugin. In particular to open a new window, you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. See :help rails-gf for docs.

Comment: This works for opening the file under the cursor, but not for opening corresponding files, like :Rcontroller does.  However, it did point me back to the docs again, where I found the answer.